# Default to array when value is null or false

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

I'm working with [ACF](https://advancedcustomfields.com/) in WP which provides a [`get_field()`](https://advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function. The function can return an array of values, `null` or false. When the result of the function doesn't contain an array of values I want to default to an empty array.

This is how I do it at the moment but would like to know if there's a neater way to accomplish the same thing.

```php
// can these lines be combined into one without multiple function calls?
$field = get_field('mobile_menu', 'option');
$field = $field ? $field : [];

return collect($field); // other processing
```

Comment: CodeReview Search: [`[php] elvis`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+elvis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shake Rattle and Roll `?:`

The ternary short cut `?:` , A.K.A. ["the Elvis operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993409/1575353) has been [available since PHP 5.3](https://www.php.net/releases/5_3_0.php).

[image: Elvis face superimposed with characters]

It could be used to simplify that second line:

> ```
> $field = $field ? $field : [];
> ```

to:

```
$field = $field ?: [];
```

That could be used on the line where `get_field()` is called:

```
$field = get_field('mobile_menu', 'option') ?: [];
```

which would allow for the elimination of the second line.

At that point `$field` is a single-use variable and can be eliminated:

```
return collect(get_field('mobile_menu', 'option') ?: []);
```